# refering to an outer method inside define_singleton_method in ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have some scope problems in my code and I really don't know how to solve them.

I have this code

```
class MainClass

    def methodOfMainClass
        #do something
    end

    def test obj
        obj.instance_variables.map do |attribute|
            obj.define_singleton_method(:something)  do |arg|
            self.methodOfMainClass()
        end
    end
end
```

when i execute it, raises **NoMethodError**: undefined method `methodOfMainClass' for

```
    #<Obj:0x0035f6274c9g12>
```

but methodOfMainClass is not from Obj, is from MainClass. How can i refer to the correct class inside the **define_singleton_method** method?

Comment: You're going to have to show us how you execute it.  There's too much left out of the question.  Please provide a minimal example that we can execute to replicate.

Comment: Is `obj` even of type `MainClass`, or is it another type?  If it is, why are you passing it as a argument? etc.

Comment: thats my problem, obj is from another class

Comment: The original question needs to say that, and it needs to provide a minimal example that can be copied and executed to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In ruby `self` is a method, not a reference.  When you create a singleton method in an object that calls `self` and then run it, it will refer to that object at run time, not the object that created the method.

Here's something that does what you're asking, though I cannot imagine a use case for it.  Make the method you want to invoke in MainClass a singleton method of the class (a class method), and then invoke it naming the class from the other object's singleton method.

```
class OtherClass
  def initialize(ivar1: nil, ivar2: nil)
    @ivar1 = ivar1
    @ivar2 = ivar2
  end
end


class MainClass

  def self.methodOfMainClass
    puts "method #{__method__} called"
  end

  def test(obj)
    obj.instance_variables.map do |attribute|
      method_name = attribute.to_s.gsub(/@/,'')
      obj.define_singleton_method(method_name) do |arg|
        puts "#{__method__} called with #{arg}"
        MainClass.methodOfMainClass
      end
    end
  end

end

my_instance = MainClass.new
other = OtherClass.new(ivar1: 'hello', ivar2: 'world')

my_instance.test(other)
other.ivar1('something')
other.ivar2('else')
```

Output:

```
ivar1 called with something
method methodOfMainClass called
ivar2 called with else
method methodOfMainClass called
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to make a class method for some reason, you can create a reference to self outside the singleton method definition and use it inside:

```
class OtherClass
  def initialize(ivar1: nil, ivar2: nil)
    @ivar1 = ivar1
    @ivar2 = ivar2
  end
end


class MainClass

  def methodOfMainClass
    puts "method #{__method__} called"
  end

  def test(obj)
    ref = self
    obj.instance_variables.map do |attribute|
      method_name = attribute.to_s.gsub(/@/,'')
      obj.define_singleton_method(method_name) do |arg|
        puts "#{__method__} called with #{arg}"
        ref.methodOfMainClass
      end
    end
  end

end

my_instance = MainClass.new
other = OtherClass.new(ivar1: 'hello', ivar2: 'world')

my_instance.test(other)
other.ivar1('something')
other.ivar2('else')
```

Output is the same as before, but this will fail as soon as the instance of MainClass goes out of scope.